# Two conjugated verbs in a row?

Tags: gramática, verbos, conjugación

In this sentence there are two conjugated verbs in a row but I don't understand it.  When I started learning Spanish I was taught that it should always be verb + infinitive.

> qué debería considera la gente cuando toma este tipo de decisiones

Can someone explain this to me please? Why don't we say "qué debería considerar" instead?

Comment: I got it in a message from a native Spanish speaker.

Comment: Thanks everyone.  I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right about the rule you were taught, the sentence should be:

> qué **debería considerar** la gente cuando toma este tipo de decisiones

Most probably it was a typo, since the sentence you received doesn't make sense otherwise.